# Speech to Text for Unsupported Language

Tags: nlp, transfer-learning, speech-to-text

I'm working on a project to plug the good old speech recognition in my app. However, I wish to do it in my country's dialect which is not supported by the major APIs like Azure, AWS, etc.

My country's national language is supported by them and this dialect is pretty similar. So I'm wondering whether is it a good idea to customise these pre-trained models or should I just start from scratch.

Thanks and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We have got a solution here... I am looking forward to implementation

https://twitter.com/sanchitgandhi99/status/1588229020642000897?t=-dE67lrM7dIVLlaxHDiz7w&s=19

https://twitter.com/version7_8/status/1713830002620354840?t=Gmu1fDeUVL7eiLfsm-4XMA&s=19